# Same button height in all browsers

Tags: html, css, styling

It appears that buttons style differently in every browser. I specifically am trying to have all buttons height the same in all browsers. I have tried many different suggestions and posts and I cannot get anything to work. I need it to be the same in IE8+, Chrome, and Firefox. Also this is the current doctype I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

This is an old website and I need to maintain that doctype because there is a bunch of deprecated styling that is used.

If it was html5 then I would just use something like:

```
input[type="button"], 
input[type="submit"], 
input[type="reset"], 
input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button, 
button {
    line-height:30px !important;
}
```

Which works in chrome, but firefox and IE don't seem to be responding to this (maybe because they strictly enforce the particular doctype?)

I know there is a jquery approach, but I'm not trying to check which browser is being called on every postback to style them.

If someone has a silver bullet in css that would be optimal, but I'm willing to settle for a minimalist javascript approach, if one even exists.

Comment: Have you tried to set `height` instead of `line-height`?

Comment: Yes... firefox and ie do not respond to that selector at all

Comment: I see... If I remove `input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button,` from the selectors, your CSS seems to style a button in all those three browsers (using `height`). Maybe you need to create a "private" rule for the webkit-specific selector?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't have an issue with this:

```
input[type="button"], 
input[type="submit"], 
input[type="reset"], 
input[type="file"], 
button {
    height:30px; //Don't use the !important keyword if you can help it!
    box-sizing: border-box; //Makes working with dimensions a bit easier
}
```